# How to get a JProgressBar to go to the "wait" screen

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar

So, I want my progress bar to go to this sorta wait screen:

[image: Progress]

Not really much else to say. Anyway I can set it to do this instead of the old percent thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`JProgressBar#setIndeterminate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html#setIndeterminate(boolean))

You would use it, very simply, like...

```
JProgress bar = new JProgressBar(...);
bar.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Then instead of showing the progress, it will show its look and feel's indeterminate state, which should be a pretty animation under the Windows look and feel...

You may also find [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) a pratical resource